# Django forms vie direct api access in browser

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-auth and when I hit the url /rest-auth/login I see something like following:

[image]

I want to replicate something similar, I have a model called ***Farm*** with few attributes like name, address etc. and basically I will have a form on my client side and posting that form data will save a Farm object in my database.

So far, I have a form created as follows:

```
class FarmForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Farm
    fields = ['farm_name', 'address']
```

and a view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addFarm(request):
form = FarmForm()
if request.POST:
    form = FarmForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        farm = form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Thank you")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Form not valid")
```

I want o have a pure rest API, no django templates in this case. I have a url `url(r'^farms/save/$', views.addFarm),` to save a Farm, but when I hit this url in browser, I see like following:
[image]

1. Why can't I see a form like login in my case? What extra I have to do?
2. Posting raw data from my form like `{"farm_name":"my farm","address":"my address",}` gives me  "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 47 (char 46)" error. **Why? What am I missing?**
3. Is there a clean way in case of pure rest API to handle forms? Is there any tutorial which shows a simple model, corresponding ModelForm and a view that handles POST requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` method cannot be directly use from the browser. I suggest to use a HTTP client like https://www.getpostman.com/ to simulate POST HTTP request.

If you want to try if your method works, you could try to change the method to `GET`.

This is a clean way using `django-rest-framework`. With very little code, you could setup TEST API with web forms http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer